# construct array from react props using ES6 map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to construct an array in this form:

```
 droppableIds = {
    droppable1: 'list1',
    droppable2: 'list2',
    droppable3: 'list3'
  }
```

At the moment it is hard coded but I want to abstract it to handle different numbers of lists. I have got this far but am getting tripped up on the correct syntax:

```
  droppableIds = this.props.boxes.map(function(index) {
    const n = '' + index; //convert to string
    return droppable + n + ':' + 'list' + n
  });
```

props.boxes looks like this

```
console.log('this.props.boxes: ', this.props.boxes, typeof this.props.boxes, Array.isArray(this.props.boxes));
```

returns:

this.props.boxes: Array(3) object true Array(3)

```
console.log(this.props.boxes)

0: {title: "Soft Targets", group: "1"} 
1: {title: "Hard Targets", group: "2"} 
2: {title: "Start ", group: "0"}
```

Comment: That's an object in your first snippet, not an array. What does your `this.props.boxes` array look like?

Comment: Is `this.props.boxes` an array or an object?

Comment: Maybe your confusing an es6 Map object with the array.map function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
vs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: To make your question complete please provide the props object as input and adjust for the desired output. This way the answers received would be much more accurate and to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This done with ES6 looks like this:

```js
var boxes = [{
    title: "Soft Targets",
    group: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Hard Targets",
    group: 2
  },
  {
    title: "Start",
    group: 0
  }
]

var droppableIds = boxes.map((x, i) => ({ [`droppable${i+1}`]: x }))

console.log(droppableIds)
```

Not sure exactly the purpose of it. Initially I was thinking you wanted to have the actual properties listed etc. In either case

```
boxes.map((x, i) => ({ [`droppable${i+1}`] : x }))
```

Is what should do it for you by:

1. Using a ES6 map with arrow function `.map((x, i) =>` where `x` is the next item and `i` the current index in the function
2. Using template literal `droppable${i+1}` where we up `i` with 1 since your desired result starts from 1
3. Composing the final return object with [] notation [`droppable${i+1}`]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to convert boxes into an object with key/value pairs matching the index as you iterate over boxes. If that's the case, you'd want to use reduce, not map (since droppableIds is an object, and map ALWAYS returns an array).

So.

```
droppableIds = this.props.boxes.reduce(function(memo, val, index) {
  memo['droppable' + index] = 'list' + index;
  return memo;
}, {})
```

You see I am passing a function as the first argument to reduce, and a new object as the second argument. There's no need to convert the index number, as coercion will do that the minute you try and add it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `this.props.boxes` is an array you could use a `forEach` function and a [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to produce the results you're after.

If `this.props.boxes` has a structure like this `['list1','list2','list3']` you could do the following (basic example).

```
let droppableIds = new Map();

this.props.boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
   let key = droppable+index;
   droppableIds.set(key, box);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to construct an object `{}` and not an array `[]`. Assuming that `this.props.boxes` is an array, one method of constructing your object would be to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const droppableIds = this.props.boxes.reduce((res, val, idx) => {
  return { ...res, [`droppable${idx + 1}`]: `list${idx + 1}`}
}, {})
```

`idx + 1` because from your example it looked like you wanted your keys and values to start at 1 rather than 0.

EDIT: I should also add, that since you asked for ES6, I used string [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), object [spread synax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

Map will return an array. You can use forEach function of loop through boxes and add properties how you want to add, for your case this will work

```
const droppableIds = {};
     this.props.boxes.forEach(function(box , index) {
     const n = '' + index; 
     droppableIds['droppable'+n] = 'list'+n;
});
```